# Sink does not release file

Tags: r, sink

I know that the `sink()` function can be used to divert R output into a file, e.g.

```
sink('sink-closing.txt')
cat('Hello world!')
sink()
```

Is there a simple command to close all outstanding sinks?

Below, I elaborate on my question.

Suppose that my R-script opens a `sink()` in an R-script, but there is an error in the R-script which occurs before the script closes the `sink()`. I may run the R-script multiple times, trying to fix the error. Finally, I want to close all the sinks and print to the console. How do I do so?

Finally, in the interest of concreteness, I provide a MWE to illustrate the problem I face.

First, I write an R-script `sink-closing.R` which has an error in it.

```
sink('sink-closing.txt')

foo <- function() {
  cat(sprintf('Hello world! My name is %s\n', 
              a.variable.that.does.not.exist))
}

foo()

sink()
```

Next, I `source` the R-script multiple times, say 3 times by mistake as I try to find and fix the bug.

```
> source('~/Dropbox/cookbook/r-cookbook/sink-closing.R')
Error in sprintf("Hello world! My name is %s\n", a.variable.that.does.not.exist) : 
  object 'a.variable.that.does.not.exist' not found
```

Now, suppose that I am debugging the R-script and want to print to the console. I can call `sink()` multiple times to close the earlier sinks. If I call it 3 times, then I can finally print to the console as before. But how do I know how many sinks I need to close?

Comment: Can you use `sink.number`?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use `sink.number()` to tell you how many diversions are already set and then call `sink` that many times.  Putting it into a function you could have this

```
sink.reset <- function(){
    for(i in seq_len(sink.number())){
        sink(NULL)
    }
}
```

Comment: Another WIN for reading *all* the documentation in the help file! :-)

Answer (score 48):

```
closeAllConnections()   # .........................
```

I'm getting upvotes for this as time goes along but Simon.S.A and others are better.

Comment: ... now why wouldn't they link to that or mention it in the sink help file?

Comment: They didn't exactly hide the fact that it was a type of connection. And there is a link to the `connection` page. So it ended up being a two-hop link to `?showConnections`.

Comment: @Dason -- Probably because `closeAllConnections` is a pretty crude tool to use for this purpose, as it will close any other connections that are open -- not just the currently open 'sinks'.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien It's a good point - but I don't think it would hurt if it was at least mentioned in the documentation for sink.

Comment: And for me this has the added benefit of also closing the processes spawned and not terminated by running a `foreach` loop in RevolutionR on Windows!  Double whammy, thanks :-)

Answer (score 9):

Based on @mnel's comment:

```
sinkall <- function() {
  i <- sink.number()
  while (i > 0) {
    sink()
    i <- i - 1
  }
}
```

Should close all open sinks.

You may also encounter this problem when dealing with devices and plots, where the number of open devices isn't reported anywhere. For a more general case you could use this:

```
stopWhenError <- function(FUN) {
  tryCatch({
    while(TRUE) {
      FUN()
    }
  }, warning = function(w) {
    print("All finished!")
  }, error = function(e) {
    print("All finished!")
  })
}

stopWhenError(sink) # for sink.
stopWhenError(dev.off) # close all open plotting devices.
```

**EDIT:**
`sink` throws a warning not an error so I've modified the code so that it won't run forever, whoops!

Answer (score 6):

#### Avoid the problem entirely

This problem can be avoided through the use of the 'on.exit' function:

```r
sink("output.txt")
on.exit(sink())
my_function_that_might_error()
```

---

#### Explanation

The most common time I experience this is when an error occurs preventing a sink from closing. For example, the following will leave an open sink after execution.

```r
sink("output.txt")
my_function_that_will_error()
sink()
```

This can be avoided using `on.exit(sink())`. This will close the sink "when the current function exits (either naturally or as the result of an error)" ([documentation here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/on.exit)).

But you do have to change the order:

```r
sink("output.txt")
on.exit(sink())
my_function_that_might_error()
```

So we create the sink, tell R to close it when it exits, and then execute the code that might error. This will close the sink regardless of whether the code errors or not.

---

#### Limitations

Note that the behaviour of `on.exit` may not work as expected when running interactively. If the line `on.exit(sink())` is run at the console, it triggers immediately as all of the current commands have concluded.

Hence, this approach requires either sourcing a script or the sink being created and closed within some R function/process.

See the documentation for `on.exit` for more information.

Comment: Excellent advice. This comment should be getting more upvotes.