# how to save the console in R to a file?

Tags: r, regression, glm

It's me again, quite the beginner at R but somehow fumbling my way through it for my thesis. I've run a bunch of regressions and made them into tables using Stargazer. Now I need to share all these results (the glm models/their summaries/the coefficients and confidence intervals and the stargazer tables ... basically everything in my console) with a friend of mine to discuss, but I figure there's got to be a more efficient way to do this than 1) screenshot-ing the hell out of my console or 2) copy and pasting the console and thus botching the formatting. Does anyone have any advice for this?

Some of my code (the rest is just variations on the same stuff) is below in case that's helpful!

```
Mod4 <- glm(`HC Annual Total` ~ `state population`
           + Year + `Trump Presidency`, data = thesis.data, family = poisson())
summary(Mod4)

#pulling the coefs out, then add exp for what reason I don't remember
exp(coef(Mod4))

#finding the confidence intervals
exp(confint(Mod4))

#Using stargazer to turn Mod4 into a cleaner table
library(stargazer)

stargazer(Mod4, type="text", dep.var.labels = c("Hate Crimes"),
          covariate.labels = c("State Population", "Year", "Trump Presidency"),
          out = "models.txt")
```

Comment: Try creating a document in RMarkdown: rmarkdown.rstudio.com

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670299/using-stargazer-with-rstudio-and-knitr

Comment: Also supporting the suggestion to use R markdown. Your question sounds *exactly* like the main use case that Rmd was invented for ...

Answer (score 4):

When you need it fast and without art, you could send console output to a simple text file using `sink`.

```
sink(file="./my_code.txt")  ## open sink connection

timestamp()
(s <- summary(fit <- lm(mpg ~ hp, mtcars)))
cat('\n##', strrep('~', 77), '\n')
texreg::screenreg(fit, override.se=s$coe[,3], override.pvalues=s$coe[,4])
cat('\n# Note: 
    We could report t-values 
    instead of SEs\n')
cat('\n##', strrep('~', 77), '\n')
cat('\nCheers!\nJ')

sink()  ## close it!


file.show("./my_code.txt")  ## look at it
```

Note, that you can easily create a mess with unclosed sinks and no output is shown on the console. Try `closeAllConnections()` in this case or perhaps [milder solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18730491/6574038). Also consider `rmarkdown` as suggested in comments.

Comment: After the sink command, you won't see the output from any other commands on the command line, so this is a bit risky unless the user knows exactly what to do.

Comment: @dash2 That's not entirely true, since after the second empty `sink()` normal behavior will be reestablished. But regardless you made a point.

Answer (score 1):

I think `reprex` is an intermediate solution between `rmarkdown` and `sink`. At first, make sure your R script can be executed without any errors. Then use the following code:

```
library(reprex)
r.file <- "path/to/Rscript/test.R" ## path to your R script file
reprex(input = r.file, outfile = NA)
```

There will be four files created in the directory of your R script file, i.e.

1. ***test_reprex.R***
2. ***test_reprex.html***
3. ***test_reprex.md***
4. ***test_reprex.utf8.md***

The `html` and `md` files contain codes in your original R script and their output. You can share with someone and they can see the output without running any codes.

The `html` file looks like:

[image]

Comment: The `outfile` argument of `reprex()` is deprecated as of reprex 2.0.0.
ℹ Use `reprex(wd = ".")` instead of `reprex(outfile = NA)`.

Answer (score 0):

`savehistory()` is your friend:

```
savehistory(file = "my-code.txt")
```

You can then edit the code at will.

Or, in RStudio, you can use the history pane and copy and paste relevant bits to a text file.

If a full rmarkdown document is overkill, you could try using `knitr::spin()` to compile your code.

Lastly:

- In future, always write scripts.

Reproducibility is best thought of at the start of a project, not as an add-on at the end. It's much easier to run a carefully-written script at the console, than it is to turn your meandering console input into a useful script. A good workflow is to try a few things at the console, then once you know what you are doing, add a line to your script.

Comment: `savehistory` just save code, not output. The question looks like the OP want to share his output in console.